# Docker compose unque container name and hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose

can I knoq, if i plan to set container_name and replica 3 in my docker compose, how to have unique name as the 3 container can't have same name. Also hostname. How can it be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is NO.

From [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#container_name):

> **container_name**
>
> Specify a custom container name, rather than a generated default name.
>
> `container_name: my-web-container`
>
> Because Docker container names must be unique, you cannot scale a service beyond 1 container if you have specified a custom name. Attempting to do so results in an error.
>
> > ***Note when using docker stack deploy***
> >
> > The container_name option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode

As mentioned above, if you explicitly set a container-name, then it won't use the default generated one, it can't work with `replicas`. The only way is let it generate the container-name for you, then it would follow the rule next which looks the only way to be compatiable with `replicas`, as it uses `sequencenumber` to distinguish different containers:

```
<currentpath>_<servicename>_<sequencenumber>
```

Comment: we cant append sequencenumber with default name?